# Why the local time zone gotten from Date function varies from time to time in Javascript/ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, react-native, date

I have a function that takes year, month, and date into Date object.

```
let date = Date(year, month, date);
console.log("date.getTimezoneOffset(): ", date.getTimezoneOffset());
```

This is the result in a span of 1 min:
[image]

Why it's varied like this? How can I make that it's consistent according to the local time zone?

Note: this is using iOS simulator, the time zone is set manually using the computer time date configuration to Mountain Daylight Time.

Comment: What you exatly want to do?

Comment: Are you using the same values for year, month and day every time? Looks like various dates, some when daylight saving is in effect and some not. BTW, *Date* called as a function returns a string, presumably you're doing `new Date(...)`.

Comment: @ZainShabir some date operation went wrong, shifting date on its own, etc. I'm just trying to find loose ends, and then I found this. So I want to know whether this is a usual occurrence or not.

Comment: @RobG ah yea sorry I already used the `new` keyword in my code, it's just not get copied into the code above.

Comment: @RobG oh wait, now that I re-read your comment, maybe it indeed has something to do with the daylight saving time. Let me check again.

Comment: @ChenLiYong—it's a bit weird as I can't find anywhere that has +6 standard time and +7 DST. In fact, nowhere that has +6 (from Antarctica/Vostok to Asia/Dhaka to Indian/Chagos) uses DST [according to IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). However, there might be historic periods with different offsets related to major events, e.g. around 1900 or 1940 – 1945.

Comment: @RobG from the timezone I set manually, this was on the US, mountain daylight time, which is probably GMT-6 or something.

Comment: @ChenLiYong—ah yes, ECMAScript offsets are backwards… 360 is -6, doh. [24timezones.com](https://24timezones.com/) provides a list of timezones and dates for changes between [-7 standard](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/utc-7) time and [-6 DST](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/utc-6) which is Mountain Daylight Time (among others).